# Kivy apps on retina screen (OS X) are blurred

Tags: macos, retina-display, kivy

I run kivy example app and it's blurred on Mac Book Pro with Retina.
I think it's because x11 through xquartz doesn't support retina. Can I fix that (change window manager etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's any way to fix this with the pygame backend, but we're moving to an sdl2 backend by default, which may well work better with this. If you're interested in testing it, it would be interesting to see if it fixes your issue.

Edit: Actually, it may have a similar issue right now, but with sdl2 it's much more likely we can solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Good news. I hope changing to SDL2 helps. SDL 2 added Retina support to its API - http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/6a05d7352575
What can I do for testing it?

Comment: You'll need to clone kivy from master, compile with `USE_SDL2=1 make force`, and run kivy apps with `KIVY_WINDOW=sdl2 KIVY_IMAGE=sdl2 KIVY_CLIPBOARD=sdl2  KIVY_TEXT=sdl2 python main.py`. Ask on kivy's irc or mailing list if you have problems, this is changing rapidly right now and there'll probably soon be an easier way.

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the makefile?

Comment: I tried to copile kivy from master with this flag, but I need help:


    `MacBook-Pro-Dmitry:kivy Dvor_nik$ USE_SDL2=1 make force`
    Result is: `make: *** No rule to make target `force'.  Stop.`



What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get another error: 
`MacBook-Pro-Dmitry:kivy Dvor_nik$ USE_SDL2=1 make force  
python setup.py build_ext --inplace -f  
Environ change use_sdl2 -> True  

Cython is missing, its required for compiling kivy !  


Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "setup.py", line 96, in <module>  
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext  
ImportError: No module named Cython.Distutils  
make: *** [force] Error 1`  

But I already installed cython with pip install cython: 
`
MacBook-Pro-Dmitry:kivy Dvor_nik$ pip list  
Cython (0.21)  
pip (1.5.6)`

Comment: Kivy build still saying `use_sdl=false`. How do you turn it on? I have already install sdl2 via brew, and have already `USE_SDL2=1` on bash prompt...